# Would a meta-question about citation expectations be useful here?

Tags: discussion

https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3583 and https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8697 are examples of other sites documenting their citation expectations? Do we want to do something similar (citing sources is after all, at the heart of what genealogists do!)

Comment: Favorited because i wanted to bookmark the RPG.SE example which is awesome. This is exactly the kind of thing I'd love to see on the site. However, if we do one answer, community-wiki style, I'd like to see clearly defined sections for questions and for answers.

Comment: A good question (and yes, I think it would be useful). The Chemistry stack has a [Citation FAQ](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4294/faq-how-should-i-use-external-sources-on-chemistry-stack-exchange?answertab=oldest#tab-top) too, which covers (and links further to) a range of topics.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to see more citations, and more background information generally, in many of the questions and answers here.

However, if we become too insistent upon citations I think we risk being offputting to those early in their journey to discover their genealogy and family history.

If we create such a Q&A then I think it should try to steer askers and answerers towards providing more citations, and be cautious about any insistence that they always provide them, which could suppress how many questions are asked here when we are far from reaching our target of 10 questions per day.

This Q&A may have some elements in common with an earlier one of [Dealing with broad questions that ask for "any information about <person/family/etc>"?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/dealing-with-broad-questions-that-ask-for-any-information-about-person-family)

Comment: It would at least support the inevitable comment: tell us how you already know what you think you know. I wasn't thinking of going full-blown ESM on everyone, but a citation could be something as simple as: I've seen the birth certificate, or we found a census entry.

Comment: For answers, too, SE already discourages people posting short answers with no explanations or one-link answers. A Meta Q/A could expound on why questions and answers need supporting information.